# Ubuntu on Matebook D14

Tags: 64-bit

The new version of ubuntu is compatible with the Huawei Matebook D14 (Ryzen 5 3500u)? I have been looking for information about this on the internet and have not found an answer

Comment: Neither will you get one here. We do not provide hardware recommendations. Ubuntu is free, can be started from a live session so you can check if it all works by booting with one. So go visit your nearest hardware dealer and ask if you can check it.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic. Questions like yours maybe more appropriate on Ubuntu Forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/)